# Why does a year 0001 appear on my blogdown / hugo blog?

Tags: hugo, blogdown

On my blog, I get a year `0001` that has a single empty post from `January 1`. I thought it was because I had a `.bib` file in `/content/post`, so I added `"\\.bib$"` to ignoreFiles in `config.toml`. It didn't help -- can anyone?

Comment: That typically means a certain post doesn't have a date. Please provide a reproducible example (and screenshots if possible).

Comment: For the record: it went back to normal after I changed a short, innocent-looking md to Rmd. It did have a date in the header, and the file name started with a date. I think I will stick to Rmd in the future. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After changing all source files from *.md to *.Rmd it worked fine.

Comment: wow, this worked. Just to clarify, if you add a new post with a `.md` file just convert the extension to `.Rmd` and everything works

Answer (score 0):

For me the cause of this error (year set to 0001-01-01) was a different dash char. ‑ instead of -

```
print(ord('‑')) # 8209
print(ord('-')) # 45
```

Never thought it could be the case.